# Corollary counter in SVmono

Tags: theorems, counters, sv-classes

When using the predefined Theorem and Corollary commands using the Springer template `svmono`, the theorem and corollary counters are different.  How can I make the counters match?  The desired effect is to have

Theorem 1.

Theorem 2.

Corollary 3.

Theorem 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `svmono` class has its own method for defining theorem-like environments:

```
\spnewtheorem{<env>}{<label>}[<within>]{<label font>}{<body font>}
```

or

```
\spnewtheorem{<env>}[<counter>]{<label>}{<label font>}{<body font>}
```

The former syntax corresponds to `\newtheorem{<env>}{<label>}[<within>]`, the latter to `\newtheorem{<env>}[<counter>]{<label>}`. There is also

```
\spnewtheorem*{<env>}{<label>}{<label font>}{<body font>}
```

for unnumbered environments.

The class predefines a `theorem` environment in one of these formats

1. `\spnewtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}{\bfseries}{\itshape}` is the default;
2. `\spnewtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]{\bfseries}{\itshape}` if the `envcountchap` class option is specified;
3. `\spnewtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]{\bfseries}{\itshape}` if the `envcountsect` class option is specified.

The class also predefines several environments:

```
\spn@wtheorem{case}{Case}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}
\spn@wtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}
\spn@wtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}{\bfseries}{\itshape}
\spn@wtheorem{definition}{Definition}{\bfseries}{\rmfamily}
\spn@wtheorem{example}{Example}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}
\spn@wtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}{\bfseries}{\rmfamily}
\spn@wtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}{\bfseries}{\itshape}
\spn@wtheorem{note}{Note}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}
\spn@wtheorem{problem}{Problem}{\bfseries}{\rmfamily}
\spn@wtheorem{property}{Property}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}
\spn@wtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}{\bfseries}{\itshape}
\spn@wtheorem{question}{Question}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}
\spn@wtheorem{solution}{Solution}{\bfseries}{\rmfamily}
\spn@wtheorem{remark}{Remark}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}
```

It uses internally `\spn@wtheorem` so that these definition can be adjusted according to another class option; if `envcountsame` is specified among the class options, all these environments will be subordinate to `theorem`.

There are also two predefined unnumbered environments:

```
\spnewtheorem*{claim}{Claim}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}
\spnewtheorem*{proof}{Proof}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}
```

### Example

```
\documentclass[
  envcountsame,% all theorem-like environments are subordinate to theorem
  envcountchap,% theorem is subordinate to chapter: `Theorem <chap>.<theorem>'
%  envcountsect,% theorem is subordinate to section: `Theorem <chap>.<section>.<theorem>'
]{svmono}
\usepackage{fix-cm}% or \usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}
\section{Title}

\begin{lemma}
Something
\end{lemma}

\begin{theorem}
Something
\end{theorem}

\begin{corollary}
Something
\end{corollary}

\begin{theorem}
Something
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

### Final word

Nobody forces you to use the `\spnewtheorem` command and the predefined environments, but probably copy editors at Springer will be happier if you do. If you use `svmono` for your personal usage, you shouldn't: the class is not the best you can find, in my opinion. For your own monograph use `memoir`.

Answer (score 2):

Will this do?

```
\documentclass{svmono}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}
\section{Title}

\begin{lem}
Something
\end{lem}

\begin{thm}
Something
\end{thm}

\begin{cor}
Something
\end{cor}

\begin{thm}
Something
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]